# Show wait div until server response in ajaxForm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('#reset_btn').click(function () {

        $("#Sender").val("");
        $("#message").val("")
    });
    $('#form1').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var user_phone = $('<?php echo $type;?>[name=Sender]').val();
            var user_message = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
            var proceed = true;
            if (user_phone == "") {
                $('<?php echo $type;?>[name=Sender]').addClass('inp-form-error');
                proceed = false;
            }
            if (user_message == "") {
                $('textarea[name=message]').addClass('form-textarea-red');
                proceed = false;
            }
            if (proceed) {
                $("#wait").show();

                if (response.type == 'error') {
                    output = '<div id="msg_1" class="error_msg_003"><div id="image" class="msg_003_image"></div>' + response.text + '</div>'
                } else if (response.type == 'warning') {
                    output = '<div id="msg_1" class="warning_msg_003"><div id="image" class="msg_003_image"></div>' + response.text + '</div>'
                } else {
                    output = '<div id="msg_1" class="success_msg_003"><div id="image" class="msg_003_image"></div>' + response.text + '</div>'
                    // output = '<div class="alert alert-success"><a href = "#" class = "close">&times;</a>'+'<strong>'+response.title+'</strong>'+response.text +'</div>'
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $('#contact_form input').val('');
                    $('#contact_form textarea').val('');

                    var credit = $.ajax({
                        url: "balance.php",
                        async: false
                    });
                    $("#credit").html(credit.responseText);

                }
                $("#result").hide().html(output).show();
            }
        }
    });
    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form input, #contact_form textarea").keyup(function () {
        $('textarea[name=Recepient]').removeClass('inp-form-error');
        $('<?php echo $type;?>[name=Sender]').removeClass('inp-form-error');
        $('textarea[name=message]').removeClass('form-textarea-red');


        $("#result").slideUp();
    });

});
</script>
```

I am trying to show `$("#wait").show();` until the server response returns. I am confused where to put "Wait" `div`. It should show waiting `div` until server response .

There was sleep of 5 second on server script to check if the wait `div` was working.

Comment: What is a `divergent` in this context?

Comment: I guessed it refers to a `<div>` element.

Comment: @Pointy: Ah... that would be `division` then :)

Comment: <style>
div#wait
{
    display: none;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    position:  absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    z-index:2;
}    

</style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show it in the `beforeSubmit` event option.

```
$('#form1').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: function(){
            $("#wait").show();
        },
        ...
```

then hide it in the success function (which is called at the end of the loading).

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#wait").hide();
    ...
```

Comment: @myeishvar: "its not working" is the single least useful comment you can make on SO. Care to provide actual details of the non-workingness? :) I put in the missing comma in case you left that out :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this $("#wait").show() inside beforesubmit event of ajax request and $("#wait").hide() in ajax success event.

Comment: It is a not an "ajax request". It is an `ajaxForm` plugin call, but the details are almost correct. It is a capital `S` in `beforeSubmit` :)